# RGBA border on ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

So I'm using this: `border-left:1px solid rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.61);` of course is not working on IE, and I found this site: http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer that converts RGBA values for IE, now how I adapt the code below with border-left?

```
    {
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#9B606060,endColorstr=#9B606060)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#9B606060,endColorstr=#9B606060);   /* IE6 & 7 */
      zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't think IE8< has support for that, only for background color.

Comment: IE only has gradients for backgrounds, I believe. If you want to have a border gradient, you have to add a container/dummy element, and assign a width of 1px, and the `filter` + `-ms-filter` property as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fall back for IE6+ support, you can specify bkgd chunk for the png, this is a color which will replace the true alpha transparency if it is not supported. You can fix it with gimp eg.

```html
    <!--[if IE]>
       
       <style type="text/css">

       .color-block { 
           background:transparent;
           filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000); 
           zoom: 1;
        } 
div {
   background: rgb(200, 54, 54); /* The Fallback */
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); 
}
        </style>
```